# Can I upgrade My Xperia Arc S To Jelly Bean after the rooting

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, sony-xperia-arc

I am planning to root my Xperia Arc S and want to know whether will I be able to upgrade it to Android Jelly Bean.

Comment: After rooting you can install it using Jellybean custom ROM. Check this below link ;   http://www.android.gs/update-xperia-arc-paranoid-jelly-bean-4-1-1/

Answer (score 1):

Sony stopped with ICS, it didnt release Jellybean for Arc S. If you are rooted and installed CWM recovery you can install Jellybean Custom rom. There are plenty of rom available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-arc/development). Just read the instruction before installing the roms. There are roms which are only for unlocked bootloader.

Comment: Do i need to root the phone to flash custom ROM ? I have already unlocked the bootloader.. is there a difference between them?

Comment: Mostly no, but you need to have CWM recovery installed. Just follow the installation instruction given in the rom page.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the times, if not all, rooting is necessary to upgrade to a newer version, especially if it is unofficial(custom ROM). You also have much more power on your phone, but it has the drawback that the guarantee will be voided.

In your case, I have found that it is easier to upgrade. You just need to install pc-companion and after you connect the device on it, it will download the latest update(Jelly Bean).

If I were you, I would download the update first and then I would root my phone.

http://www.knowyourmobile.com/sony-ericsson/sony-xperia/17465/how-update-your-sony-xperia-arc-s-android-40

Comment: Hi I have tried to do that but it says that the phone is up to date and doesnt give an option to upgrade to 4.1 or 4.2.I have got ICS installed but is there anyway i can upgrade before i could start with the root.